modify SQL query to limit the entries
is it possible to add argument in limit statement?
the case here is i need to retrieve 5 entries of transaction history but the thing is some transactions have more than one item which causing it will just return less than 5 while actually the db already returned 5 entries but only for less than 5 transactions.
i need to retrieve 5 transactions, no matter how many item each transaction has
these are the codes i wrote
rows, err := dh.QueryContext(ctx, "select trx_id from transactions where website_id = $1 and username = $2 order by created_at desc limit $3",
        websiteId, username, 5)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var trxId string
        err = rows.Scan(&trxId)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        trxIds = append(trxIds, trxId)
    }
    if err = r.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // check if there is no transaction found.
    if len(trxIds) == 0 {
        return nil, nil
    }


    rows, err = dh.QueryContext(ctx,
        `select t.transaction_id, t.status, t.created_at, t.expired_at, pi.item_name
            from transactions t
            join transaction_items ti on t.website_id = ti.website_id and t.transaction_id = ti.transaction_id
            join product_items pi on ti.website_id = pi.website_id and pi.product_id = ti.product_id and ti.product_item_id = pi.product_item_id
            where t.website_id = $1 and username = $2 order by created_at desc limit $3`,
        websiteId, username, 5)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

it seems i can just do it in a single query since do it twice will be redundant that it does the exact same thing
anyone can help me with this?
big thanks

with x as (select dense_rank() over (order by created_at desc, t.transaction_id) as dr ... <your query>) select * from x where dr <= 5; Remove the limit. If there's zero chance for ties you can sort only on created_at rather than both columns.

If you need 5 transactions, try FROM (SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE ... LIMIT 5) AS t instead of FROM transactoins t and do without the final LIMIT.
